# Скопировать Excel строку из другого листа

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Подскажите, есть ли возможность используя Python и библиотеку openpyxl скопировать целиком строку (row) с одного листа на другой?

Например так:

```
for row in sheet:
     sheet2.append(row)
```

Сейчас такой код у меня не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данный пример добавляет вторую строку из листа `Sheet2` в конец листа `Sheet1` *с сохранением форматирования*:

```
from copy import copy
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def copy_cell(src_sheet, src_row, src_col, 
              tgt_sheet, tgt_row, tgt_col,
              copy_style=True):
    cell = src_sheet.cell(src_row, src_col)
    new_cell = tgt_sheet.cell(tgt_row, tgt_col, cell.value)
    if cell.has_style and copy_style:
        new_cell._style = copy(cell._style)

filename = r"c:\temp\test.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb['Sheet1']
ws2 = wb['Sheet2']


ws1_last_row = ws1.max_row

for i,row in enumerate(ws2.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=2), 1):
    for cell in row:
        copy_cell(ws2, cell.row, cell.column, 
                  ws1, ws1_last_row+i, cell.column)

wb.save(filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

Рабочий пример (проверено с `openpyxl 3.0.3`):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

filename = r"c:\temp\test.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb['Sheet1']
ws2 = wb['Sheet2']

# добавляем вторую строку из [Sheet2] в конец [Sheet1]
_ = [ws1.append(row) for row in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=2, values_only=True)]

wb.save(filename)
```

Comment: спасибо, код работает корректно, значения переносятся. А можно каким-нибудь образом переносить не только текст, но и свойства ячейки. Например цвет фона и шрифт? Если я пишу `values_only=False`, то возникает ошибка `Cells cannot be copied from other worksheets`

Comment: @Евгений, [см. пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1092109/211923)